# What's the best way of implementing a finite state machine in C++

Tags: c++, fsm, state-machine

I've seen a number of different approaches to implementing a FSM.

Switch-case
Function pointer tables
object oriented programming

My question is what are the main factors I should be aware of when choosing one implementation over the other. In my case I only have 4 states with at most 2 transitions at each state. My main goal is for the implementation to be easily readable for someone else to modify.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at boost msm. You can see the advantages vs disadvantages in their documentation as well. In this very simple state machine you described this might be an overkill, but msm will provide a very readable transition table

Comment: One thing you could consider I guess is to use a boost spirit qi parser for the FSM? Since you say your FSM is small -- if it very naturally corresponds to regular expressions and you think that would be simpler than writing a transition table, then doing it in a grammar form (with semantic actions?) might be worth considering. If you studied theory of computation at something like university level then you probably at some point learned that FSM and (simple) regular expressions are formally equivalent (not the super regex used in like perl & grep though)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [method-based](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a6491bf3038e611) FSA implementation

```
// abstract FSA
template<class C, typename T>
struct fsa {
    struct state_t {
        typedef state_t (C::*type)(T);
        inline state_t(type f) : state(f) {}
        type state;
    };

    fsa(state_t init) : state(init) {}

    inline bool next(T val) {
        state = (static_cast<C*>(this)->*state.state)(val);
        return state.state != nullptr;
    }
private:
    state_t state;
};

//concrete FSA implementation
struct myfsa : fsa<myfsa,char> {
    inline myfsa() : fsa<myfsa, char>(&myfsa::start) {}
    state_t start(char) {
        std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
        return &myfsa::state1;
    }
    state_t state1(char) {
        std::cout << "state1" << std::endl;
        return &myfsa::state2;
    }
    state_t state2(char) {
        std::cout << "state2" << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    char get() { return ' '; /*TODO*/ }
    void run() {
        while(next(get()));
    }
};
```